# bat file stops executing after calling another bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have a bat file which calls another bat file. All this works successfully. The other bat file produces an xml file that I then want to move to another directory, but my bat file never gets that far, instead stopping at frmf2xml. I'm not very experienced in writing them so any help or guidance would be great

```
echo.
echo.
echo [ RUNNING CONVERSION ]
echo.
echo before........................

frmf2xml USE_PROPERTY_IDS=NO OVERWRITE=YES %inputFMB%\%1

echo after.........................
move /-y "C:\resources\fmb\%1_fmb.xml" "C:\resources\xml\"
```

Comment: Always include the file extension when you call something though a program, shortcut, or batch file. If two files have the same name and different extension, the OS will decide which one to execute and that is not reliable.

Answer (score 4):

This is intended - or at least documented.

You must use `call` in order to proceed with the calling batch file:

```
call frmf2xml USE_PROPERTY_IDS=NO OVERWRITE=YES %inputFMB%\%1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
call batfile.bat
```

Solution 2:

```
cmd /c batfile.bat
```